# mount error "is not a block device"

Tags: mount

I am trying to make `olddir` accessible from `newdir` with the mount command:

```
mount olddir newdir
```

Why do I get the following error?

> mount: olddir is not a block device

Answer (score 20, accepted):

mount attaches block storage devices that contain a filesystem to a directory, which is not what you're trying to do, hence the error message.  What you want is to create a link from the new directory name to the old existing name.  For that you must use the `ln` command to create a symbolic link.

```
ln -s olddir newdir
```

Comment: I'm trying what you suggested, but instead of linking from olddir to newdir, it create a symlink called olddir inside newdir. So for example, after doing `ln -s /olddir /newdir` I end up with /newdir/olddir@ which links to /olddir. How do I make it do what you said?

Comment: **newdir** should be the name you want created that points back to **olddir**.  **newdir** should not already exist.

Comment: I totally understand what you mean, and that's what I'm trying to do, but it's doing something really odd, completely different. `/olddir` exists, and `/newdir` does not exist. Then, after I run `ln -s /olddir /newdir`, it is creating `/newdir/olddir` which links to `/olddir`. I don't want it to create `/newdir/olddir`. I want it to create `/newdir` only, which should link to `/olddir`, but that's not what happening. So instead of making `/newddir`, it is making `/newdir/olddir`. It's so weird!!! Get what I mean?

Answer (score 41):

On Linux one can perform a **bind mount**, which will splice an existing directory to a new mount point.

```
mount --bind <olddir> <mountpoint>
```

Solaris supports an alternate syntax:

```
mount -F lofs <olddir> <mountpoint>
```

*BSD uses `mount_null` instead (although it does not come with OS X).

```
mount_null <olddir> <mountpoint>
```

Comment: Exactly the answer!

Comment: What are the differences (pros and cons) between this and a soft link?

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio mount binds are useful if the user needing the directory can't gain access to it otherwise, or if a disk doesn't support softlinks. Binds are more powerful and will work more often. Binds work because the kernel sort of 'lies' to the application and tells it a directory contains contents that is actually somewhere else. Binds don't however persist across reboots unless you add it to `/etc/fstab`. If in doubt, us `ln -s` - it's easier, more flexible, doesn't require root, will tell you where the actualy directory is, etc. You generally don't need a binds.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Speacialy when dealing with legacy softwares

Answer (score 4):

## If you're trying to mount a logical HDD/SDD

- I dual boot: Windows 10/Ubuntu
- I found this searching for a way to mount my Windows drive in Linux

### Steps Taken

- show block devices

  > ℹ️ *your HDD/SDD is a block storage device*

  ```
  sudo blkid
  ```

  ```
  /dev/sda5: UUID="a6aa3891-1dc2-439a-b449-b9b1848db028" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="e4887e0f-05"
  /dev/sda1: LABEL="System" UUID="C6F4E92AF4E91E05" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e4887e0f-01"
  /dev/sda2: LABEL="Windows" UUID="4ABAF478BAF461BD" TYPE="ntfs" PARTUUID="e4887e0f-02"
  ```
- In my case, I want to mount the device labeled "Windows" `/dev/sda2`

### What didn't work

- Turns out I reversed the `mount` command arguments to get the **"is not a block device"** complaint

  ```
  mkdir Windows
  sudo mount Windows /dev/sda2
  mount: /dev/sda2: /home/casey/Windows is not a block device.
  ```

### What *did* work ‍♂️️

- `mount` works like a boss when you list the arguments in the right order!

  ```
  sudo mount /dev/sda2 Windows 
  cd Windows 
  ls
  Config.Msi                hiberfil.sys   Intel         pagefile.sys   ProgramData     'Program Files (x86)'  '$Recycle.Bin'  'System Volume Information'   WCH.CN
  'Documents and Settings'   home           msdia80.dll   PerfLogs      'Program Files'   Recovery               swapfile.sys    Users                        Windows
  ```

Comment: Thanks, I reversed the order too

Answer (score 0):

When use `mount shareddir newdir`, I get the same, then I appoint the nfs server host to mount, it turns ok. The command like:

```
mount host:shareddir newdir
```

Answer (score 0):

This could also happen when you mess up the external device and mounting point:

```
sudo mount external_device mount_point // OK
sudo mount mount_point external_device // NOT WORKING
```

I did it once and got the same error

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/my_usb  // OK
sudo mount /mnt/my_usb /dev/sdb1  // WRONG
```